# How to resolve "it" or "there" during dialog with WIT.AI bot

Tags: nlp, wit.ai

Consider the scenario:

```
User> Show me Seattle
AI> Sure, Seattle is on the map
User> Take me there
AI> Starting navigation to Seattle
```

In other words, does wit.ai allows "there" or "it" resolution on back end? Or should I collect the inferences on application side and resolve "it" myself?
Do you know of any NLU platforms that allow resolution of "it/there"?

Answer (score 2):

Currently wit doesn't have this feature, which is called **Coreference Resolution**.
You should use other libraries, like [neuralcoref](https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref) that implement an state-of-the-art [Deep Reinforcement Learning method](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/kevclark/resources/clark-manning-emnlp2016-deep.pdf).

Comment: Thank you! However, I tried the example above and neuralcoref did not detected coreference b/n _there_ and _Seattle_